# What ways are there to sort an apache log by date?

Tags: python-3.x, apache, datetime

I'm writing a script that reads through an apache log and appends the IP address and date from each row into two lists, list_date and list_ip. I want to sort the list_date so that I'm able to print all the dates starting with the oldest date first.

I've tried looking for answers here on Stackoverflow but I haven't seen anything useful since all the posts and answers seem to be with PHP or some other language.

This is what a row looks like in the apache log:

```
109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
```

And this is what my code currently looks like:

```
list_ip = []
list_date =[]
with open('accseslogsmall.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        IP, date = line.partition("]")[0].split(" - - [")
        list_date.append(date)
        list_ip.append(IP)

print(list_date)
print(list_ip)
```

This is what I get currently:

```
['12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100', '12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100', '12/Dec/2015:18:31:08 +0100', '12/Dec/2015:18:31:08 +0100', '12/Dec/2015:18:31:25 +0100']
['109.169.248.247', '109.169.248.247', '46.72.177.4', '46.72.177.4', '83.167.113.100']
```

And ideally, I would want the dates to be sorted from oldest to newest.
After this, I would like to know how I make the IP addresses to sort according to the dates. Because right now the first in both of the lists are on the same row (if that makes sense?)

Comment: Can you add what you get at the moment and what output you want to receive ?
Have you tried `list_date.sort()` and than 
`print(list_date)` or just `print(sorted(list_date))`

Comment: Oh now I haven't, But do sort() work here? The type of list_ip and list_date is str.

Comment: It does works on strings, it will sort it in lexicographic order. But in your case you need to treat it as dates. You can see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest using the  [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module in order to represent the Date strings as date objects in Python.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

list_date = ['12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100', '12/Dec/2015:18:31:08 +0100', '12/Dec/2015:18:31:25 +0100',
             '12/Dec/2016:18:25:11 +0100', '11/Dec/2015:18:31:08 +0100', '13/Dec/2015:18:31:08 +0100']
# Parse the date strings into date objects, you can read more about the format in the link
_list_date = [datetime.strptime(i, '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z') for i in list_date]
list_ip = ['10.0.0.11', '10.0.0.22', '10.0.0.13', '10.0.0.24', '10.0.0.15', '10.0.0.26']

# Creating a DataFrame with two columns Date and IP
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': _list_date, 'IP': list_ip})
print(df)
                       Date         IP
0 2015-12-12 18:25:11+01:00  10.0.0.11
1 2015-12-12 18:31:08+01:00  10.0.0.22
2 2015-12-12 18:31:25+01:00  10.0.0.13
3 2016-12-12 18:25:11+01:00  10.0.0.24
4 2015-12-11 18:31:08+01:00  10.0.0.15
5 2015-12-13 18:31:08+01:00  10.0.0.26


# Sorting the DataFrame by date
df = df.sort_values('Date')
print(df)

                       Date         IP
4 2015-12-11 18:31:08+01:00  10.0.0.15
0 2015-12-12 18:25:11+01:00  10.0.0.11
1 2015-12-12 18:31:08+01:00  10.0.0.22
2 2015-12-12 18:31:25+01:00  10.0.0.13
5 2015-12-13 18:31:08+01:00  10.0.0.26
3 2016-12-12 18:25:11+01:00  10.0.0.24
```

[Date Format documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

If you just want to sort the dates, w/o using Pandas you can run

```
print(sorted(list_date, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z')))
['11/Dec/2015:18:31:08 +0100', '12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100', '12/Dec/2015:18:31:08 +0100', '12/Dec/2015:18:31:25 +0100', '13/Dec/2015:18:31:08 +0100', '12/Dec/2016:18:25:11 +0100']
```